# Замена ссылки при изменении чекбоксов на странице

Tags: javascript

Всем привет

Часnо сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда нужно готовое переправить под себя. Особо остро это чувствуется на JS скриптах, где есть конструкции IF-ELSE.

```
// работающий код
<input type="checkbox" onChange="changeButton(this.checked);">
<a id="1" href="index.php?f=1"><img src="img/key.gif"></a>

<script>
function changeButton(checked) {
    if (checked === true) {
        document.getElementById('1').href = 'index.php?f=2';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('1').href = 'index.php?f=1';
    }
}
​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Собственно все весело работает. нажимаем галочку, ссылка меняется, отжимаем - ссылка меняется на первоначальную. Можно ли как то модернизировать этот скрипт на 2 галочки? Что бы ссылок к фактически было 4?

если первый и второй checkbox не нажат - ссылка 1, если второй нажат - ссылка 2, если первый нажат - ссылка 3, если оба нажаты - ссылка 4

Comment: 1. Взрыв мозга но можно

2. Ловите добровольца который сядит за вас писать скрипт

Comment: @frank, с т.з. архитектуры - правильнее было бы отправить данные на обработчик, а оттуда уже переправить на необходимую страницу. + такая конструкция `href="index.php?f=1"` неканоннична. Смотрите рефернес

Comment: ну, всего 2 чекбокса, не 22, в теории это по любому быстрее чем с помощью POST'ом отправлять куда то данные и там формировать ссылку

Comment: @frank, я писал о "правильнее", а не о "быстрее" :)

Comment: Про правильнее соглашусь! Но  иногда 1 раз быстро > 2 раз правильнее. Сейчас вот думаю, над глубокой мыслью в посте @lampa

Comment: А чем правильнее то? Переносить логику с клиента на сервер? Ради чего? Чтобы дополнительную нагрузку получить? Ох.

Comment: Как раз таки на оборот. ( Может я чего то не понимаю? ) Если мы чекбоксы засовываем в форму, данные нужно куда то передавать, там формировать ссылку... это дольше! Все то же самое можно загрузить сразу, и сформировать ссылку сразу.

Я сам от JS не в восторге, и люблю делать все на PHP/HTML. В данный момент как раз все так и работает. Но с JS реально удобнее, в первую очередь в плане нагрузки на железо

Comment: @frank я о том, что клиент это javascript, а сервер - php в вашем случае. JS вообще клевая штука, со временем понимаешь, в чем её мощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" id='checkbox1'>
<input type="checkbox" id='checkbox2'>

<a id="href1" href="index.php?f=1">img</a>

<script>
(function() {
    /**
     * подсыпем сахарка
     */
    var ById = function (a) { return document.getElementById(a);}

    /**
     * объявляем наши чекбоксы и ссылку
     */
    var first_checkbox  = ById('checkbox1');
    var second_checkbox = ById('checkbox2');

    var href_tag        = ById('href1');

    /**
     * сама функция
     */
    var check_checkbox = function() {
        if(!first_checkbox.checked && !second_checkbox.checked) {
            href_tag.href='index.php?f=1';
        }
        else if(!first_checkbox.checked && second_checkbox.checked) {
            href_tag.href='index.php?f=2';
        }
        else if(first_checkbox.checked && !second_checkbox.checked) {
            href_tag.href='index.php?f=3';
        }
        else if(first_checkbox.checked && second_checkbox.checked) {
            href_tag.href='index.php?f=4';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Вешаем на чекбоксы обработчики, по старинке
     */
    first_checkbox.onchange = second_checkbox.onchange = check_checkbox;

    /**
     * 
     */
})();
</script>
```

как-то так.

Comment: @frank подправил.

Comment: Вау! Работает! Прекрасно работает. Признаюсь думал нужно мою вышеописанную конструкцию модернизировать, так я бы и сам больше узнал. Хотя данный код хорош, как не крути. Спасибо.

Comment: @frank, я вам показал некие "секретики", про которые Вы теперь просто обязаны прочитать и взять на вооружение!)

Comment: Копать в эту сторону я еще буду долго и упорно